# Emacs "start-server" does not change variable "server-mode"

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

I'm running Emacs 23 in Debian Squeeze. `~/.emacs` does not contain any `server`-related commands.

I launch Emacs and enter `C-h v server-mode`, which returns `nil`, as no server is running. I then enter `M-x start-server`, which starts an Emacs server in the running instance of Emacs.

However, the variable `server-mode` is still `nil` when I check it again. Only after running `M-x server-mode`, does variable `server-mode` get a value of `t`. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Server-mode **works** fine after entering `start-server`; I can use `emacsclient` to open a file in the Emacs server. However, I wanted to use variable `server-mode` in the mode-line to indicate if the server is running, but if starting the server with `start-server` does not change the value of `server-mode`, this will not work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

A better way is to use `(server-running-p)` from `server` package. For example

```
(require 'server)
(unless (server-running-p)
    (server-start))
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the functionality I need/expect (from a freshly-started Emacs), I run `M-x server-mode` to start the server, rather than `server-start`. Starting the server this way changes the value of variable `server-mode` to `t`.

I do not understand why starting the server with the [documented](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html) `server-start` does not set the variable `server-mode` to `t`.